# Need suggestion on simultaneous submission in journal and conference

Tags: journals, ethics, conference, paper-submission, extended-paper

Is it correct to submit a revised version of a paper to the same journal while some application part of the paper is under review in a conference?

I have received a request for revisions on a journal paper, and am thinking to submit some part of it to a conference. I can't wait for the conference decision, as that will cross the journal revision deadline. Therefore, my question is can I submit it to the same journal while the paper is under review in conference.

The conference and journal version have similarities, but they are significantly different at the same time.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? You send a paper to a journal, you got a major revision result, you now submit the revised version back and you concurrently send another paper based on the journal version?

Comment: @Alexandros: Thanks for the reply. I have not yet submitted the revision. I am thinking to submit  some part of it to a conference. I can't wait for the conference decision as that will cross the journal revision deadline. Therefore my question is can I submit it to the same journal while the paper is under review in conference. I asked the editor of the journal on this, he has not replied yet, wants to know suggestion of experts in this forum.

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: @TomChurch: Stochastic Approximation. This is a mathematics paper, but the application part is machine learning. In other words it is a operations research paper. But, the theoretical part has significant mathematics. My department is computer science. It is slightly messed up.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've gone in the wrong order, here.  In computer science, it is common practice to initially publish a work in a conference, then the follow it by an extended version in a journal, which is more thorough and takes into account all of the feedback from the conference and advances during the time since the conference version was completed.

Going the other way, however, strikes me as unethical and a form of self-plagiarism.  You have already produced a journal-scale paper, and mining a smaller conference paper out of it is just double-publication.  Now, in certain cases a conference might accept this if explicitly declared (there are some conferences that have a special track for reports on journal publications).  If the conference expects original work, however, you cannot ethically submit your paper to the conference.

Comment: A pre-emptive comment to others: the ethics of situations like this are HUGELY field-dependent. If you disagree with this answer and are in another field than CS, you should post your own answer (and note what field you're in), not downvote this one. [I say this as someone who is not in CS.]

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly valid to send *different* aspects of the same work to separate venues. You must make sure to cross-reference (as "submitted to..." if need be), and that they don't overlap too much.

Answer (score 0):

In some engineering fields rather than CS, most of the conference papers are not peer-reviewed. Only the abstracts are reviewed to determine whether it can be presented in a conference. In such case, I think the authors can extend the conference paper for a peer-reviewed journal paper. By pulishing on peer-reviewed journals, especially good or top journals, you can get constructive suggestions from your peers and experts about your reseach. And your results are more reliable.